# 'npm install firebase' throwing 10 high severity vulnerabilities on M1 apple

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, electron

I am trying to install firebase for my electron app

using command - npm install firebase

'npm audit' shows this output, can you help ?

---

node-fetch  <2.6.7
Severity: high
node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install firebase@8.6.8, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/node-fetch
node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/node-fetch
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/node-fetch
node_modules/@firebase/functions/node_modules/node-fetch
node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch
@firebase/auth  <=0.0.900-exp.f919db6a9 || 0.17.0-20217250818 - 0.19.6
Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
node_modules/@firebase/auth
firebase  0.800.3 - 0.900.25 || 7.9.1-0 - 7.9.1-canary.0396117e || 7.17.1-20206244562 - 7.17.1-canary.f1299756 || 7.17.2-20206291717 - 9.6.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/auth
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/auth-compat
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/firestore
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/functions
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/storage
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/storage-compat

Comment: Try removing the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and again do `npm i firebase`

Comment: thanks @Kundan for your response
but i see the same output after performing the above steps

Comment: Created an issue on the github repo (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5944) This is going to be taken care of in next release.

Comment: Created an issue on Github repo, corrected in latest vision